# Audio matrix using ESP32 and relays

Tags: audio, esp32, solid-state-relay, matrix

I want to build a matrix for a pre-amplifier and a second ine for my amplifiers and speakers. The pre-amp one is not my main concern now.

I have 6 amps and 3 pairs of speakers, and I want to be able to use input 1 on both output 1 and 2. I have 32 solid-state relays and an ESP32 for the project. Will this be more or less what I should do or not?

[image]

Comment: It's hard to understand what kind of signals you are switching, but no matter if it is speaker level, line level, mic level, or instrument level, almost always a solid state relay is not the correct part for audio switching. But yes, the diagram depicts a matrix of any kind with signal path, so at a very conceptual level, it might be what you want, but without details, the implementation is unknown.

Comment: You cannot use solid state relays with audio signal they won't work with small signal.

Comment: @Dorian some will work fine; some won't; it depends on the tech.

Comment: This really confuses me --> *I have 6 amps and 3 pairs of speakers, and I want to be able to use input 1 on both output 1 and 2.*

Comment: @Justme So what I want to switch is my amplifier output level. So let's say it's a high voltage output. I did build myself a "version 1" of this. Where I use relays and xlr cables to switch the relays on and off. Like a patch panel. But I know you get real-world products that do what I want to achieve like the Triad products from control4.

Comment: @Andyaka So see the "inputs" as the amps and the "outputs" as the speakers.

Comment: So in short, you want a matrix which simply allows to connect speakers to amplifier outputs? Which amplifiers these are, what power levels or speaker impedances or voltage levels are you talking about? How do you make sure you don't exceed rated load impedance on an amplifier by connecting too many speakers in parallel? Or that the amplifier can handle sudden impedance changes, like disconnect of all speakers? Which solid state relay you have to figure out if it can handle the voltages and currents involved in connecting speakers to amps?